# Using spring3 @Value to access PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer values?

Tags: spring, spring-el

I'm trying to set the value of a string in a spring bean using `@Value`, when my property source is a subclass of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 15):

Old question, but still worth to be answered. You can use the expression the same way as you would with the original `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

app.properties

```
    app.value=Injected
```

app-context.xml

```
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="location">
        <value>file:app.properties</value>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

in the target bean

```
    @Value(value="${app.value}")
    private String injected;
```

Tested this approach using Spring 3.0.6

Comment: The extra #{...} is sort of useless (it does a SpEL evaluation of a static string). Since Spring 3.x, the ${app.value} syntax is supported in @Value annotations, and can be used to inject the property (but it probably wasn't at the time this question was asked).

Comment: You are correct regarding the extra #{...}. You can omit it and you will achieve the same result. I will correct my answer to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you managed to get it to work by explicitly injecting the value from the bean definition file using the property syntax? In theory, if that works, then you should be able to use the same expression in `@Value`. For that matter, you should be able to do it using `@Autowired @Qualifier` also

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to access properties loaded by `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` using SPEL in a `@Value` annotation. It would be great, but as far as I know, the next best thing is to declare:

```
<util:properties id="props" location="classpath:xxx/yyy/app.props"/>
```

It can point to the same properties file as your `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`.

Comment: You can also create your own PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer which exposes its properties.  You can find an example of this here: http://mortarproject.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mortarproject/src/trunk/mortar-core/src/main/java/org/mortar/spring/beans/factory/config/EnhancedPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java?revision=70&view=markup  You will have to register it using the old <bean id="xxx"> instead of the newer <context:property-placeholder> so you can set an id an then refernce it in your value tag as @Value(#{xxx.properties['foo.bar']})

Comment: I don't think you need to put xxx.properties file name, spring loads all the properties files, you just have to make sure that your key is unique among all the properties file.

Comment: This is incorrect.  As of spring 3 you can access PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer values using SPEL.