# Injection of null or an empty string as the default value of a property

Tags: spring

Is it possible to inject a null or blank string as the default value that will be used in a spring file if the property is not specified? Currently the best I have is

```
<constructor-arg index="1" value="@{data.url:&quot;&quot;}"/>
```

which resolves to `""` in code

Comment: I think just `<constructor-arg value=""/>` should work. In case you need the index you may add it. Maybe I am not getting your question right?

Comment: <constructor-arg value=""/> will always send an empty string. I'm interested in an empty string only if one is not specified in the associated properties file. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2534949/222867

Answer (score 15):

Empty-Elvis works for me...

```
@Value("${http.proxyHost?:}")
public String proxyHost = null;
```

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen generates an expression expected warning when I do this. It does work, though. I'm guessing this is an Eclipse issue.

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried using [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)? Something like this maybe:

```
<constructor-arg index="1" value="#{'${data.url}'==null?'':'${data.url}'}"/>
```

**Update**

I just remembered that there's an easier way (as nicely described [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-default-values)). Try:

```
<constructor-arg index="1" value="${data.url:''}"/>
```

Comment: In Spring 3.0.7 I made "#{ '${data.url}' != 'null' ? '${data.url}' : '' }" because just != null doesn't worked

Answer (score 13):

This will do the trick if you are using annotations in your source:

```
@Value("${data.url:#{null}}")
private String dataUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to set value as **null**:

```
@Value("${data.url:#{null}}")
private String dataUrl;
```

2. If you want to set value as **empty string**:

```
@Value("${data.url:}")
private String dataUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

To inject an empty string as the default value, you can use the @Value annotation with the defaultValue attribute

```
@Value("${data.url:}")
private String dataUrl;
```

you can also define the property like:

```
@Value("${data.url:#{null}}")
private String dataUrl;
```