# property not found with multiple context:property-placeholder

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using spring 3.1 with spring profiles to load the beans. In my app context file, I load the properties like :

```
<context:property-placeholder order="1"  location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*_${spring.profiles.active}.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

And then I use the property value to load the data source bean like

```
<property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
```

It works fine.
The problem starts when I add a couple of more property placeholders so that properties from some database tables can be loaded.

This uses a properties reference loaded by

```
<bean id="configFactoryBean"
class="org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean">
   <constructor-arg ref="globalSystemConfiguration"/>
</bean>
```

To add to the details, this `configFactoryBean` uses the `datasource` to load the properties from the database.

When I do this, I have the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${database.driverClassName}
```

My analysis is that its trying to load the `datasource` before resolving the property from the first context property placeholder. I may be wrong. Or maybe spring profile variable is not resolved properly.

Can anyone please help me to fix this.

Thanks
Akki

Comment: Try setting the order to 0

Comment: No. it doesn't work. I changed order to 0 for the first one and still have the same error.

Comment: Oh wait, its not finding your database driver.  Have you added it to the classpath?

Comment: yes. and it works if i remove the other two <context:property-placeholder..> tags. I think it is not able to resolve the property ${database.driverClassName}

Answer (score 11):

This bug about multiple property placeholders might relate to your problem: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9989

> When using multiple `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in conjunction with
>   `@Value` annotation and default value for placeholders syntax (ie
>   `${key:defaultValue}`), only the first `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is
>   used. If this configurer does not contain the desired value, it falls
>   back to `@Value` default even if the second
>   `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` contains the value.
>
> Affects Version/s: 3.1.3

Answer (score 4):

In my application I am using property-placeholder configurer in following way and it works very well. You can try that.

```xml
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
          <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/*_${spring.profiles.active}.properties</value>
            </list>
          </property>
    </bean>
```

I think this should resolve your problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

Each **<context:property-placeholder> creates a new instance of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** - it gets messy easily. You should have one such thing per application and on application level, not on libraries' one - that makes maintenance much easier.

For more details and a suggestion how to cope with it look here:
http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.cz/2013/06/resolving-properties-with-spring.html

Comment: But `order` attribute introduced to resolve this issue (instead of creating a new instance reuse and maintain a chain of property sources). Currently  https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9989 is open.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have suggested hardcoding the path to the configuration file works, try using the profiles attribute on the tag to selectively include the configuration.

```
<beans profile="profileName">
    <context:property-placeholder  order="1"  location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/hardcoded.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
</beans>

<beans profile="profileName2">    
    <context:property-placeholder order="1"  location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/hardcoded.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
</beans>
```

See this article explaining profiles: http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml

Comment: It works if i remove the other two <context:property-placeholder..> tags. It's not able to resolve the property i guess

Comment: Do the other two property-placeholders have an order specified?

Comment: @user1517723 How does `CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean` play a part?

Comment: it creates a properties object from the org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration as i load the properties from the database. this internally uses the datasource specified

Comment: @user1517723 I can't even find that thing in the documentation anywhere, I did find a forum post saying it wasn't supported in Spring 3.x here: http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-125884.html

Comment: @user1517723 Are you missing the .jar file containing `CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean`?

Comment: If CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean is not supported, how I load the properties from database by using xml bean definitions

Comment: I think I have a problem with spring profiles. When I remove the profile specific attribute from the first context properties placeholder and manually hardcode a profile, it works. Why is the second placeholder causing a conflict with spring profiles

Comment: Can you post the config for the second placeholder or is this coming from CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean?

Comment: its coming from CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean.

Comment: I don't think your first property placeholder is actually being loaded. So the app can't make the database connection to get the other properties.

Comment: What can be the problem. If I remove the second placeholder, everything works fine

Comment: I tried the example at forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-125884.html but I still have the same problem. Any ideas? Am really stuck here