# El expression with Spring

Tags: spring, expression

I work on a new application and I found this xml in an applicationContext:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:conf/taskExecutor-${my.env:test}.properties, classpath:conf/application-${my.env:test}.properties" />
```

I know el expression in Spring and it's the first time where I see an el like this:

```
${var:something}
```

What is the expression after the ':' ?

I found nothing on this in the Spring doc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax corresponds to the default value:

```
${var:defaultValue}
```

If `${var}` is not set, it will return `defaultValue`.

- [Is there a way to specify a default property value in Spring XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513484/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-default-property-value-in-spring-xml)