# How to use Spring Java properties default value in XML

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, configurationproperty

I am looking how to use the Java default properties value in XML without specifying in application YML or what ever.

This is my java configuration and default I want to use this URL value until providing it from YML file.

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test.sample")
public @Data class SampleProperties {
   private String serverurl ="test.example.com";
}
```

When I try to use in XML

```
<property name="serverURL" value="${test.sample.serverurl}" />
```

Throwing

```
IllegalArgumentException : Could not resolve placeholder 'test.sample.serverurl' in value "${test.sample.serverurl}"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of the placeholder in XML does not include a default value to use when it is missing

Default values can be provided with a `:default-value` suffix on the placeholder

```
<property name="serverURL" value="${test.sample.serverurl:http://localhost}" />
```

The example is complicated by the `:` in the default value, simpler ones might be

```
value="example:default"
value="test.sample.port:8080"
```

There is a probable duplicate [Is there a way to specify a default property value in Spring XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2513484/134894). Here is a [decent tutorial on properties in Spring](http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring).