# Can I define an application.properties file value as optional

Tags: spring-boot, properties

In my application.properties file I would like to have an optional value. Such as spring.datasource.url=${value} but optional 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a property as "optional" by giving it a default value where you inject it.

For example:

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.url:null}")
private String springDatasourceURL;
```

Comment: To my knowledge, no.

Comment: check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513484/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-default-property-value-in-spring-xml  It may be what you want.

Comment: based on that question, it looks like defaults can be set in xml configuration as well.

Comment: uncheck correct answer if 2513484 answers your question and we can mark this as a duplicate.