# Set log4j default path in java

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I want to set default file path for my application, in case ${custom.log.path} is not defined or by any means can't be created than logs should be generated at default location.

I am using spring application, not sure how to configure the default file path.

log4j.properties :

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${custom.log.path}/Application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this topic and answers: [Is there a way to specify a default property value in Spring XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513484/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-default-property-value-in-spring-xml)

Spring Framework supports the following syntax:
`${my.variable:defaultValue}`

Comment: I tried ${custom.log.path:"D:/HelloWorld/"} it didn't work

Comment: Try something like this: ${custom.log.path:#{"D:/HelloWorld/"}}. If this also does not work, is there any exception/log stacktrace about it?