# Referencing a property of the current bean in Spring EL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I'd like to create a number of beans from a single class, all to be instantiated in the current application context, each based on prefixed properties in a properties file. I've given an example of what I'm trying to achieve. Any tips on how to do this without excessive code (e.g. without multiple classes, complicated factories, etc.) would be appreciated.

XML configuration:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="Mybean">
    <property name="prefix" value="bean1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bean2" class="Mybean">
    <property name="prefix" value="bean2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bean3" class="Mybean">
    <property name="prefix" value="bean3"/>
</bean>
```

Properties File:

```
bean1.name=alfred
bean2.name=bobby
bean3.name=charlie
```

Class:

```
class Mybean {
    @Value("${#{prefix}.name}")
    String name;
}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Main {
    @Autowired
    List<MyBean> mybeans;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to set bean's name directly (instead of storing its prefix):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="app.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bean1" class="Mybean">
    <property name="name" value="${bean1.name}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bean2" class="Mybean">
    <property name="name" value="${bean2.name}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bean3" class="Mybean">
    <property name="name" value="${bean3.name}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you'd reference the resulting property in Spring EL in a @Value annotation?

Comment: I think you find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041558/how-does-spring-3-expression-language-interact-with-property-placeholders?rq=1)

Comment: That explains how to reference data in the Spring property placeholder bean. It does not explain how to reference properties defined on the *bean* being configured.

Comment: Evaluation of `@Value` takes place in bean post processor. Probably, you cannot refer property of the bean that is in process of initialization.

Comment: So there's basically no way of providing information in a property set on the bean definition to the bean post processor? That doesn't seem logical.

By the way, the reason I need this to be available in a @Value annotation is I'm setting dozens of fields on the bean, and I *really* don't want to add dozens of property values on every bean, I'd rather let provide a prefix and let Spring calculate these fields for me.