# Injecting property values from property file or function

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, configuration, annotations

I'd like to set a java property with a value from my properties file or, if it doesn't exist, from a function.

Pseudo code might look like this -

```
@Value("${server.thread.count:Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()}")
private int numOfThreads;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041558/how-does-spring-3-expression-language-interact-with-property-placeholders

Comment: Thanks!
I found my answer down there - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29603277/3052112