# Access a property from .properties file within SpEL expression

Tags: xml, spring-integration, spring-el

I need to build a dynamic path combining a value defined in properties file  with the result of a SpEL expression and can't find the right syntax to achieve that.

my situation is something like:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:myprop.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="fileNameToFSTree"
    class="foo.bar.FileNameToFSTree"/>

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut"
    auto-create-directory="true"
    directory-expression="${outDir} + @fileNameToFSTree.nameToTree(payload)"
    delete-source-files="true"/>
```

given that `myprop.properties` file contains a variable `outDir`, I'd like to prepend that variable in the `directory-expression` of the file outbound.

apparently it regularly evaluates `${outDir}` but I got the following exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [/tmp/output + @fileNameToFSTree.nameToTree(payload)] @0: EL1070E: Problem parsing left operand
```

I've found no traces of that case in the docs or in the examples.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

find this answer just after posting the question:

[How does Spring 3 expression language interact with property placeholders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041558/how-does-spring-3-expression-language-interact-with-property-placeholders)

basically, the syntax is:

`directory-expression="'${outDir}' + @fileNameToFSTree.nameToTree(payload)"`

Comment: That's correct.  Because property placeholder is resolved first. Then its result becomes a part of an expression syntax. So, if the story is just about string value, we need to wrap property placeholder into the quotes.