# How can I inject a property value into an annotation configured spring mvc 3.0 controller

Tags: java, spring

First: I'm using Spring 3.0

I have a problem when configuring my controller class. The controller uses a web service which I want to define the endpoint address using a .properties file.

```
@Controller
public class SupportController {

    @Value("#{url.webservice}") 
    private String wsEndpoint;

    ...
```

In my application context xml-file, I've defined this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/*.properties" />
```

I've been reading the documentation, trying different approaches (like adding prefix *systemProperties.*),but I keep getting an error message telling me that it doesn't exist.

> Field or property 'url' cannot be
>   found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'

---

Ok. I've figured it out.

Now, in the controller:

```
@Value("#{settings['url.webservice']")
```

Then in the context configuration I have this "helper bean":

```
<util:properties id="settings" 
location="/WEB-INF/supportweb.properties"></util:properties>
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741968/using-spring3-value-to-access-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-values

Answer (score 12):

This should work, too:

```
@Value("${url.webservice}") 
private String wsEndpoint;
```

Answer (score 3):

I have this configuration and it works fine:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
       <list>
         <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
      </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and I iniejct the property in this way

```
@Value("${root.log.level}") 
private String prop;
```

the field is correctly initialized to "DEBUG" value.

Answer (score 2):

you should check that the

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/*.properties" />
```

is defined in webmvc-config.xml where you create instances of the @Controllers