# Spring MVC: @Value annotation to get int value defined in *.properties file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a config.properties file:

```
limit=10
```

My springmvc-servlet.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config/config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is my controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(...)
public class Test extends BaseController
{
    @Value("${limit}") Integer limit;   // This doesn't work
    @Value("#{T(java.lang.Integer).parseInt(${limit})}") Integer limit;   // This also doesn't work

    @RequestMapping(...)
    @ResponseBody
    public String session()
    {
        return String.valueOf(limit);
    }
}
```

error message is:

```
Error creating bean with name 'test': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: java.lang.Integer **.Test.limit; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 31): Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lcurly({)'
```

any ideas?

Comment: Use an `int` instead of an `Integer`. I would also suggest using `<context:property-placeholder />` instead of the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Saves you some XML and in newer spring versions it will give you the more powerful `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Comment: @zccode: `@Value("${limit}") Integer limit` should work. What is the error message in this case? Which spring version do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
@Value("#{config.limit}") Integer limit;
```

Documentation at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html

Example given there is:

```
@Repository 
public class RewardsTestDatabase {
    @Value("#{systemProperties.databaseName}")
    public void setDatabaseName(String dbName) { … }

    @Value("#{strategyBean.databaseKeyGenerator}")
    public void setKeyGenerator(KeyGenerator kg) { … }
}
```

UPDATE: I tested and had same problem. Figured it out by following instructions at [How can I inject a property value into an annotation configured spring mvc 3.0 controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055660/how-can-i-inject-a-property-value-into-an-annotation-configured-spring-mvc-3-0-c/8403308#8403308)

Answer (score 0):

In your code :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config/config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

classpath refers to WEB-INF/classes path inside war file. So do you have config folder inside WEB-INF/classes ?

If yes then check using xml based configuration as below :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.tempuri.DataBeanClass">
    <property name="url" value="${url}"></property>
</bean>
```

If still you are getting an error then there is sure issue with property file loading.

Answer (score 0):

try this : `@Value("#{new Integer('${limit}')}")`

and

```
<context:property-placeholder location="config/config.properties" />
```

Comment: no, but that's not the point. the point is, that if you didn't check, can't explain why, or simply think that this might be the answer, don't post it as answer!